# how to change styles depending of true/false in vuejs

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vuejs3

I'm trying to change the style if one of the classes returns true.

`My template-`

```
<div
  class=""
  :class="{
  ' green': visibleComponent != 'orders',
  ' opacity-25 ': visibleComponent == 'orders',
  }"
  @click="orders"
  >
  <div class="">
    Orders
  </div>
</div>
```

Any help on how do I go about this?

Comment: use `v-if` https://vuejs.org/guide/essentials/conditional.html

Comment: You are using the correct approach (you don't need the spaces around the CSS class names though). Why is it not working? Have you checked that the conditions evaluate correctly?

Answer (score 1):

this is how u do it:

```
<div class="anyclass" :class="dynamicClass" @click="orders">
  <div class="">
    Orders
  </div>
</div>

<script setup> // Composition API
  const dynamicClass = computed(() => {
    return {
      'green': visibleComponent != 'orders',
      'opacity-25 ': visibleComponent == 'orders',
    }
  })

  // Options API
  export default {
    computed: {
      dynamicClass() {
        return {
          'green': visibleComponent != 'orders',
          'opacity-25 ': visibleComponent == 'orders',
        }
      }
    }
  }
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Do this;

```html
<div 
    :class="`${visibleComponent !== 'orders' ? 'green' : 'opacity-25'}`"
    @click="orders"
>
```

Answer (score 0):

I assume you talking about `Conditional Rendering`
this offical sample code should be clear about how to use v-if

```js
<script>
export default {
  data() {
    return {
        awesome: true
    }
    }
}
</script>

<template>
  <button @click="awesome = !awesome">toggle</button>

    <h1 v-if="awesome">Vue is awesome!</h1>
    <h1 v-else>Oh no </h1>
</template>
```

Comment: and of course you can apply style on this

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you have already defined `visibleComponent` in your data object or as a `ref()` with Vue3, you could use a ternary operator inline with a dynamic class binding. This is most similar to what you are showing in your code already.

If you are unfamiliar with ternary operators, it is basically an if/else statement using shorthand.  `condition ? ifConditionTrue : ifConditionFalse` This format works very nicely with Vue dynamic class bindings.

```
<div
 :class="
  visibleComponent
   ? visibleComponent != 'orders' && 'green'
   : visibleComponent == 'orders' && 'opacity-25'
 ">
</div>
```

This first checks if the `visibleComponent` property has been assigned a value. Then if that value is not 'orders', the `green` class will bind to the div. Else if the value is 'orders', the `opacity-25` class will bind.

Answer (score 0):

Following your own case, this will work.
opacity-25 its inside quotation marks because of the dash "-".

```
<div
  :class="{ 
     green: visibleComponent != 'orders',
     'opacity-25': visibleComponent == 'orders'
  }"
  @click="orders"
  >
    <div>
      Orders
    </div>
 </div>
```